# Splitting content of arrays into different line

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to have each element of an array to start on a new line while allowing other content to be on the same line.

```
//arrays of plannames
$planname_num=array(1=>"Alpha","Omega","Gamma");

//arrays of planlevels
$planlevels_num=array(1=>"Bronze","Silver","Gold");
/* 
 * 
 * Get The Length of Plan Name Array
 * 
 * 
 */
$planname_array_length=count($planname_num);
/* 
 * 
 * Get The Length of Plan Level Array
 * 
 * 
 */
$planlevel_array_length=count($planlevels_num);

$pnArrayLength=$planname_array_length;
$plArrayLength=$planlevel_array_length;

for ($pn=1; $pn <= $pnArrayLength; $pn++) {//loop to create plan name indicators 
            for ($pl=1; $pl <= $plArrayLength; $pl++) {//loop to create plan level indicators 


             //Create pricing for each plan from db
                $getplansql = "SELECT SUM(`planPrice`) AS planPrice,planDescription FROM `plans`
                        WHERE planName = '$planname_num[$pn]' AND planLevel = '$planlevels_num[$pl]'";
                $resultplans = $conn->query($getplansql);

                while($plan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultplans)) {$i++;// output data of each row
                         //calculate sales price
                         $finalpricing = ($plan['planPrice'] * 0.7) + ($plan['planPrice']);

                //create plan card
                $resultplanarray.= '

                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                         <div class="panel price panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3>'.$planname_num[$pn].'</h3>
                                                <h3>'.$planlevels_num[$pl].'</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead panel-body-pricing" style=""><strong>$'.round($finalpricing).'/month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i>
                                                       '.$plan['planDescription'].'
                                                        </li>
                                                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">BUY</a>
                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>';

}}}


//print result outside of while loop
echo $resultplanarray;
```

This code will output as follow until the grid of 12 is filled:

```
Alpha  Alpha   Alpha Omega  Omega   Omega 
Bronze Silver  Gold  Bronze Silver  Gold
```

I'd like the array to split and print the different plan groups each on a new line like this:

```
Alpha  Alpha   Alpha 
Bronze Silver  Gold 

Omega  Omega   Omega 
Bronze Silver  Gold
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You should be able to do this with css. There is no need to add any more markup. If you post what css you have then I can advise.

Comment: @markt: Interesting. Can you provide with just a quick hint? What are you thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add outer container for all plan name

```
$planname_num = array(1=>"Alpha","Omega","Gamma");
$planlevels_num = array(1=>"Bronze","Silver","Gold");
$planname_array_length = count($planname_num);
$planlevel_array_length = count($planlevels_num);

$resultplanarray = '';
for($i = 1; $i <= $planname_array_length ; $i++)
{
    $resultplanarray .= '<div class="row">';
    for($j = 1; $j <= $planlevel_array_length ; $j++)
    {
        //YOUR QUERY DATA
    }
    $resultplanarray .= '</div>';
}
```

I have added `<div class='row'>`

Please check it and let me know if you have any issue

Comment: Hmm... Nothing on my end. Nothing changes.

Comment: @JavaNoob - sorry, I had added code with different name of " $resultplanarray .= '</div>';"
Please use update code

Comment: Dude, nice. Working.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with css without adding to the markup.

This works by styling every 3rd div from an index of 1 (`3n+1`), so will add the `clear` to divs 4,7,10 etc..

```css
.col-lg-2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.col-lg-2:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel price panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h3>Alpha</h3>
            <h3>Bronze</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel price panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h3>Alpha</h3>
            <h3>Silver</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel price panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h3>Alpha</h3>
            <h3>Gold</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel price panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h3>Omega</h3>
            <h3>Bronze</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel price panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h3>Omega</h3>
            <h3>Silver</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel price panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h3>Omega</h3>
            <h3>Gold</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```